Organization GitHub PAT doesn't work despite having permissions
I have created a Fine grained PAT for my organization to manage self-hosted runners.
Command I try to do it actions/runners/registration-token:
curl -Li   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"   -H "Authorization: Token 
github_pat_..."   -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"               
https://api.github.com/orgs/.../actions/runners/registration-token
HTTP/2 403 
server: GitHub.com
date: Tue, 07 May 2024 21:31:53 GMT
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
github-authentication-token-expiration: 2024-08-05 20:57:52 +0200
x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
x-accepted-github-permissions: organization_self_hosted_runners=read
x-github-api-version-selected: 2022-11-28
x-github-request-id: 813F:EF368:331761F7:334F3EB0:663A9DC9

{
  "message": "Resource not accessible by personal access token",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/actions/self-hosted-        
 runners#get-a-self-hosted-runner-for-an-organization"
}

But my token HAS this permission:


Your organization might have “Restrict access via fine-grained personal access tokens” set. Switch it to “Allow access”
The configuration screen is at https://github.com/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NAME/settings/personal-access-tokens.

